# Animation bug in Chrome v.36?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, fullpage.js

I've just noticed a wrong behavior of Chrome 36.0.1933.0 m rendering when using [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin.

This bug didn't took place in a previous version of Chrome and it neither does in any other browser. (IE, Opera, Firefox)

Some content suddenly disappears from the site after it is animated (It changes the `top` property of a container by using jQuery).
The content still being there in the DOM structure and there's nothing I could find to justify that behavior.

I don't know exactly what causes it and why it take place only in some "sections" of the site.

To reproduce it you can do it at the [plugin site](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/):

- Scroll down to the 2nd section
- Scroll down to the 3rd section **#problem1** (the content seems to be fixed while scrolling down)
- Scroll up **#problem2** You will see the text is no longer visible

You can also reproduce it [this jsfiddle](http://tinyurl.com/pms6cuy):

- Scroll down the 3rd slide
- Scroll down to the 4th section **#problem1** (the content seems to be fixed while scrolling down)
- Scroll up **#problem2** You will see the text is no longer visible

Comment: I'd also raise a bug with the plugin creator, assuming you haven't already.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm the plugin creator. I've sent a reported the issue to Chrome as I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Could be a redraw issue maybe. But isn't current stable chrome release 34.xxxx ?

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah, this is the Dev Channel: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/dev-channel-update_15.html

Comment: Chrome 36 is not a stable release AFAIK...it's alpha testing level isn't it? Sounds like you should be reporting a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same exact problem with the stable release of Chrome 36. If you want, check my blog post on Medium: https://medium.com/@alex89x/chrome-36-webkit-animation-su-s-5d5e85f4af6e

I'm trying to get in contact with anyone I can to let Google know this awful problem.